# Error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import pickle
import numpy as np

model = pickle.load(open('biker.pkl','rb'))


  total = [[r1,r2,r3,o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,m,g,int(yearinc),int(child),int(cars),int(cmtdist),int(age)]]
print(total)
y_pred = model.predict(total)

print(y_pred)
```

I imported a Random Forest Classification model and its giving error.
The error says that  'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'. Please help how to solve this

Comment: How are you saving this model?

Comment: What type do you expect?

Comment: @hacker315 i saved the model in .pkl format

Comment: @Joe I am expecting 0 or 1 as output

Comment: Ok, that does not answer the question... Where you are saving the model, if you add `print(type(model))` there, what does it say?

Comment: It looks to me you are saving weights, but not a complete model.

Comment: @Joe when i add print(type(model))  i am getting   <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Then 1.) you are pickling the wrong thing or 2.) you have to initialize the model using the ndarray. At some point you are trying `model.predict()`, right? What type is `model` there? Please show the code that does the pickling

Comment: import pickle
pickle.dump(randomforest,open('biker.pkl','wb'))        This is how i am doing the pickling. i dont know much about pickling cuz i just started learning ML

Comment: @Joe i found the error. i was pickling the wrong thing. Thank you for the help